# ARPG Random Item Generation with Prefix & Suffixes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I'm currently making a small game that will have "random" loot drop after an enemy dies.

Quite new to c# and unity as well.

What I'm doing here is having the itemtype, prefixtype & suffixtype as Scriptable objects the lists are pulling from Classes. Then having it randomly roll for the stats with the dice.

But I'm stuck on how i would output all three of these as 1 singular item after all three have been rolled for. So for example, ItemBase(Sword) => PrefixType (Chilled) => SuffixType (Of the Base) and then output it as one singular item rather than three individual stats.

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class Main : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] public List<Item> itemType = new List<Item>();
        [SerializeField] public List<Prefix> prefixType = new List<Prefix>();
        [SerializeField] public List<Suffix> suffixType = new List<Suffix>();
    
        [System.NonSerialized] private bool isInitialized = false;
    
        private float _totalWeight;
        private float _suffixWeight;
        private float _prefixWeight;
    
        private void Update()
        {
            GetRandomItem();
            GetRandomPrefix();
            GetRandomSuffix();
    
        }
    
        private void ItemInitialize()
        {
            if (!isInitialized)
            {
                _totalWeight = itemType.Sum(item => item.weight);
                _prefixWeight = prefixType.Sum(prefix => prefix.weight);
                _suffixWeight = suffixType.Sum(suffix => suffix.weight);
                isInitialized = true;
            }
        }
    
        public Item GetRandomItem()
        {
    
            // Make sure it is initalized
            ItemInitialize();
            // Roll our dice with _totalWeight faces
            float diceRoll = Random.Range(0f, _totalWeight);
    
            // Cycle through our items
            foreach (var item in itemType)
            {
                if (item.weight >= diceRoll)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Item: " + item.itemName);
                    return item;
                }
    
                // If we didn't return, we substract the weight to our diceRoll and cycle to the next item
                diceRoll -= item.weight;
            }
    
            // Spooky Error.
            throw new System.Exception("Reward generation failed!");
        }
    
        public Prefix GetRandomPrefix()
        {
            // Roll our dice with _totalWeight faces
            float diceRoll = Random.Range(0f, _prefixWeight);
    
            // Cycle through our items
            foreach (var prefix in prefixType)
            {
                if (prefix.weight >= diceRoll)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Item: " + prefix.prefixName);
                    return prefix;
                }
    
                // If we didn't return, we substract the weight to our diceRoll and cycle to the next item
                diceRoll -= prefix.weight;
            }
    
            // Spooky Error.
            throw new System.Exception("Reward generation failed!");
        }
    
        public Suffix GetRandomSuffix()
        {
    
            // Roll our dice with _totalWeight faces
            float diceRoll = Random.Range(0f, _suffixWeight);
    
            // Cycle through our items
            foreach (var suffix in suffixType)
            {
                if (suffix.weight >= diceRoll)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Item: " + suffix.suffixName);
                    return suffix;
                }
    
                // If we didn't return, we substract the weight to our diceRoll and cycle to the next item
                diceRoll -= suffix.weight;
            }
    
            // Spooky Error.
            throw new System.Exception("Reward generation failed!");
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Don't know exactly, what do you mean by output. Doesn't just creating class for your preffixed/suffixed item, for eg. FullItem with Item, Prefix, Sufix fields won't be enough?

Comment: @bartol44 thanks for the reply!

My issue I'm stuck with is how do i "combine" all three of these rolls and make it into a singular item so to speak.

TLDR; Roll for the Item Base Type, Axe, Sword, Shield etc, Then Roll for Affixes (i.e the prefix & suffix). Then create that as one complete item and store it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to create some structure to hold your item information, create its new object/instance, and paste the random values you got from your `Main` script.

Not really the greatest form of coding, but should give you and idea:

```
public class CompleteItem
{
    public Item item;
    public Prefix prefix;
    public Suffix suffix;

    public static CompleteItem CreateNewItem()
    {
        CompleteItem NewItem = new CompleteItem();

        NewItem.item = GetRandomItem();
        NewItem.prefix = GetRandomPrefix();
        NewItem.suffix = GetRandomSuffix();

        return NewItem;
    }
}
```

It can be class, struct, monobehaviour, scriptable object, you name it. Just keep in mind, that if you want it to be MB, you can't use `new` keyword for creating new `CompleteItem`s, other solutions may have their advantages and limitations.

Also treat it just as an idea, not a ready code to paste. For eg. `GetRandomItem()`call will fail. You will need to get reference to `Main` or find any other way to call those randomizing methods in your `CompleteItem`.

Comment: Hmmm, I'll give it a go and see what i can do. Thank you.

Comment: this doesn't seem to take the information and hold it?

Comment: It takes randomized items and prefs/sufs and hold them in fields, would you care to elaborate what you mean?

Comment: There's some chance we don't understand each other too well :P For me, it's really simple to store 3 things in another class/struct, so there's a good chance you mean much more than I thought.

Comment: The errors are on my end, I guess I'm probably trying to do something too big for my own good at this point (I'm still relatively new to this and there is probably a more logical/better way) to have RNG weapons with Prefix/Affixes.

I thought it would be more simple haha.

Right now when I generate the "weapon" it doesn't seem to hold the data that has been generated.

If you have Discord maybe that'll be easier for examples/communication as i can show more files and what im trying to achieve easier. Yami#9089

I do really appreciate you taking the time to help out a noob though!

Comment: I think i need to rethink how i want to do it.

Going to go away and completely restructure everything.